# Text Based List Of Elements

Tags: c#, wpf

Ok, So lets say i have a rectangle named rectangle1 and 2 labels named label1 and label2

Is there any way for me to get a list of the items selected from the designer ?

For example when i have all 3 items selected, is there like some hidden button that will give me a list like

rectangle1,
label1,
label2

?

Comment: do you mean at design time? or run time??

Comment: design time, for coding purposes, so i don't have to memorize the names of everything i plan on writing code for, i can just paste it  and comment it and then use it without having to go back and forth between the designer and the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see the selected controls in wpf designer down the xaml code:

[image: Selected Controls]

but if you still want text list i think you will need to create your owen plug-in

Edit: this article may give you an idea on what you want

[A-Document-Outline-Window-for-C-Files-in-WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96311/A-Document-Outline-Window-for-C-Files-in-WPF)

Comment: That's Exactly what i want, but it's not copy-pastable :(